# table cell text not updating text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a basic parking calculator. It calculates required spaces by use on a parcel.

I want to update the "units" based on the use. For example, a coffee shop units is cups while office space is sf (square feet). - silly examples.

**This only seems to work for the first row and then each row is stuck with this unit.**

**Also**, if you do not start with the first row the units don't show.

Basically when the use is changed I find the td with the class in that row. Then update the appropriate cell. Let me know if you need more code.

```
$(".useType").change(function() {

  var use = $('.useType').val();
  var units = $(this).closest('tr').find('.units');
  units.addClass('highlight');

  if (use == "General Office 25000sf") {
    units.text('sf');


  } else if (use == "General Retail") {
    units.text('aisles');


  } else if (use == "Fitness Studio") {
    units.text('weights');


  } else if (use == "Coffee Shop") {
    units.text('cups');


  } else if (use == "Restaurant (no bar)") {
    units.text('plates');


  }


});
```

I have made a fiddle example, link below, which you can see this. To test, select a use for the first table row. Then set the next. The units will match. Then change the first row to something different. Then all unites will match that when changed.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzqoub56/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector:

```
var use = $('.useType').val();
```

Is selecting the first instance with that class. Properly scope it like this:

```
var use = $(this).val();
```

As a side note, it would be better to cache `$(this)` since you're using it more than once:

```
let $this = $(this);
let use = $this.val();
let units = $this.closest('tr').find('.units');
```

Here's [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzqoub56/4/).

Lastly, your code can be greatly simplified (and more readable) if you simply store your values in a lookup of sorts. This also allows you to change/remove any values without adding additional logic.

```
$(".useType").change(function() {
  let $this = $(this);
  let lookup = {
  "General Office 25000sf": "sf",
  "General Retail": "aisles",
  "Fitness Studio": "weights",
  "Coffee Shop": "cups",
  "Restaurant (no bar)": "plates"
  };

  $this.closest('tr')
    .find('.units')
    .text(lookup[$this.val()])
    .addClass('highlight');
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzqoub56/6/).

Comment: Thank you very much James! Such a simple/obvious thing I missed. I also appreciate your quick, helpful and very nice response. I will accept when allowed.

Comment: @Eric.18 Bear with me one sec - going to post updated code.